# Customising swagger ui to separate documentation

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have integrated swagger into my Web API/OData project using swashbuckle 5.x and swashbuckle-Odata. If I navigate to http://root_url/swagger I can see all available API documentation in one big list. Every thing works perfectly fine but I have given a **list of Odata controllers and API(s)** which I need to **show in a separate list**. I know this is something which I need to do by create a custom index.html for swagger and inject into swaggerconfig.cs like

```
c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "SwaggerUI_Config.SwaggerExtensions.index.html");
```

I have been researching on internet on how I can separate swagger documentation so that I can create a different HTML list and acheive my result, so far no luck. Has anyone done something similar? Can you please give me some suggestions or pointer where I need to begin?.

I'm trying to achive following structure on my swagger documentation.

```
+ Custom API list
  +API Controller #1
   > GET API
   > POST API
   > PUT API
   > DELETE API
  +API Controller #2
   > GET API
   > POST API
   > PUT API
   > DELETE API

+ All available API(s)
  +API Controller #1
   > GET API
   > POST API
   > PUT API
   > DELETE API
  +API Controller #2
   > GET API
   > POST API
   > PUT API
   > DELETE API
  +API Controller #3
   > GET API
   > POST API
   > PUT API
   > DELETE API
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have misconstrued your requirements but you should be able to group your actions using the `GroupActionsBy` method in your `EnableSwagger` call in SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc =>
{
    string controllerName = apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    string method = apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.First().Method;

    return string.Format("{0} {1} API", controllerName, method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use @Api annotation with tags attribute provided by Swagger.  It will organize your APIs on swagger UI dashboard the way you want.
E.g.

```
@Path("apiController1")
@Api(value = "/apiController1", tags = "API CONTROLLER 1")
@Produces({
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
})
public class APIController1 {

    @GET
    @Path("fooGet")
    public final String fooGet() {
        return "Hello, World";
    }
}
```

In some other controller.

```
@Path("apiController2")
@Api(value = "/apiController2", tags = {
        "API CONTROLLER 2", "DEFAULT"
})
@Produces({
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
})
public class APIController2 {

    @GET
    @Path("fooGet2")
    public final String fooGet2() {
        return "Hello, World";
    }
}
```

and the Swagger UI Dashboard will look like this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, is this Java? I could not find @Api annotation  for swashbuckle-swagger. I'm looking for the similar functionality in ASP.Net Web API application.

Comment: Yes. That's for java.  However a quick google reveals that swagger core for swashbuckle does expose such functionality.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/Annotations/SwaggerOperationAttribute.cs

Comment: Here's a sample use of that from a blog.
http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2015/03/18/custom-operation-names-with-swashbuckle-5-0/

Comment: Thanks foryour response, but I don't think it will help me to acheive my goal. What I'm expecting to do is group controllers which contains methods like GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE etc. The above blog post help me to modify the generated action name not group controllers. Similarly the Swashbuckle annotations can only be added to methods not to group controllers.  I guess I have to find a way to modify swagger index.html and create a seaparate list for controller I need. But still dont know how to filterout the Controllers I need into a separate list.